# Align Twitter Bootstrap form groups

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying some simple examples of Twitter Bootstrap, and some that I cant do is do as one column has two lines (like if it was a table), and the best I could was this code below that is not align

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario" class="control-label">Nome</label>
            <input type="usuario" class="form-control" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario"/>
            <label for="sobrenome" class="control-label">SobreNome</label>
            <input type="sobrenome" class="form-control" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" placeholder="sobrenome"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario" class="control-label">Orgao</label>
            <input type="orgao" class="form-control" name="orgao" id="orgao" placeholder="Orgao"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario" class="control-label">Orgao</label>
            <input type="orgao" class="form-control" name="orgao" id="orgao" placeholder="Orgao"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do to put the last form group at the same direction at the other one, but with size 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can set class `.row` to eliminate the left and right margins

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="usuario" class="control-label">Orgao</label>
                    <input type="orgao" class="form-control" name="orgao" id="orgao" placeholder="Orgao" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fe4w9att/2/)**

Comment: this was great man. please, tell me where can I found these tricks to do with the bootstrap the same that we can do with tables without lose the margin